If $A_1,\dots,A_n\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ are distinct, there exists $x\in\{1, \dots, n\}$ such that $A_1\cup\{x\},\dots, A_n\cup\{x\} $ are distinct.
Let $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ be distinct subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then, there exists an element $ x \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ such that the sets $ A_1 \cup \{x\}, A_2 \cup \{x\}, \dots, A_n \cup \{x\} $ are distinct.
I can think of the case where there exist $x \in \cap A_i$ then the theorem holds and when there is x such that $x\notin \cup A_i$ then also the theorem holds.
Please give some suggestions for other cases. Not graph theoric proof.

+1 : I went back and forth on judging this posted question.  On the one hand the OP (i.e. original poster) didn't actually show any work, or provide other forms of context.  On the other hand, the actual math problem presented seems very interesting to me.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.
